# inserting into database (hibernate)

Tags: hibernate, javafx, javafx-8

I've mapped a table (mapping is correct) and now I want to add new row into this table. First of all I've binded all columns of table.

```
cb_acc_type.valueProperty().bindBidirectional(model.accTypeProperty());
tf_acc_num.textProperty().bindBidirectional(model.accNumProperty());
tf_acc_name.textProperty().bindBidirectional(model.accNameProperty());
cb_currency_add.valueProperty().bindBidirectional(model.accCurProperty());
```

and added them into `@ActionMethod`

```
@ActionMethod(ACTION_ADD_ACCOUNT)
    public void addAccount() {
        CreateAccount input = new CreateAccount();

        input.setType(model.getAccType());
        input.setAccNum(model.getAccNum());
        input.setAccName(model.getAccName());
        input.setCurrency(model.getAccCur());

        service.addAccount(input, context.getTaskView(), result -> {
            model.getAccounts().addAll(result.getAccount());
            tv_loro_nostro_accounts.getSelectionModel().selectFirst();
        });
    }
```

Here is what `addAccount()` method do

```
public void addAccount(CreateAccount input, FOTaskView view, final FOAsyncTaskCallback<CreateAccount> callback){

        HttpPostJsonTask<CreateAccount, CreateAccount> task = factory.httpPostForJson(FOContext.getLocalMessage("service.main.load_menu_operation"), "position/createAccount", input, view);
        task.setOnSucceeded(event -> {
            if (callback != null) {
                callback.onSuccess((CreateAccount) event.getSource().getValue());
            }
        });
        context.getExecutor().submit(task);

    }
```

afterwards I do this

```
@Path("createAccount")
    @POST
    public CreateAccount createAccount(CreateAccount model){
        model = operationService.execute(model,(result, userDetails) -> {
            result.setAccount(service.createAccount(result.getAccount()));
            result.setState(OperationState.DONE);
            return result;
        });
        return model;
    }
```

where createAccount() method is

```
public PositionAccount createAccount(PositionAccount account){
        repository.createAccount(account);
        return account;
    }
```

and finally in `repository` I do this

```
public void createAccount(PositionAccount account){
        em.persist(account);
        em.refresh(account);//em - EntityManager
    }
```

`PositionAccount` is a mapped class. What can be wrong with this? Here what it writes in a console

```
19:36:23.825 [pool-2-thread-1] INFO  jersey -  [] 11 * Sending client request on thread pool-2-thread-1
11 > POST http://localhost:8081/isbankInbound/issystem/position/createAccount
11 > Accept: application/json
11 > Content-Type: application/json
{
  "@class" : "ru.com.isbank.adc.adc_common.operations.position.CreateAccount",
  "sessionId" : "e8a5a3cb-26ce-44af-89d0-15e5c3457dfd",
  "operatorId" : "sm10155",
  "dateTimeSent" : 1436373383817,
  "locale" : "ru_RU",
  "type" : "Loro",
  "accNum" : "someaccnum",
  "accName" : "someaccname",
  "currency" : "EUR"
}

19:36:23.927 [pool-2-thread-1] INFO  jersey -  [] 12 * Client response received on thread pool-2-thread-1
12 < 500
12 < Connection: close
12 < Content-Length: 0
12 < Date: Wed, 08 Jul 2015 16:36:23 GMT
12 < Server: Apache-Coyote/1.1
```

Comment: *What can be wrong with this?* You should tell us. Have you run the code? What do you expect to happen, and what happens instead?

Comment: It should enter new entry into table. But I receiver error `unable to perform the query: HTTP status - 500`

Comment: So, there is an exception being thrown somewhere. An exception comes with an error message and a stack trace, explaining what and where the problem is. Read it. If you can't understand it, post it.

Comment: Actually, there is no any exception. I run it via interface, and I put what it returns in a console to the question

Comment: HTTP status 500 means "Internal Server Error". So there **is** an internal **server** error. Look in the console/logs of the **server**.